# ElasticSearch - Difference between Sub-aggregations and pipeline aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

Could somebody explain me the difference between `sub-aggregations` and `pipeline aggregations`?

For example: Which is the difference between `sum` metric aggregation inside a `term` bucket aggregation and a `sum_buckets` pipeline aggregation referenced to a `term` bucket aggregation?

Answer (score 3):

Sub-aggregations operate on individual buckets of the previous level's aggregations, where as pipeline aggregations operate "after" "normal" aggregations. For example [Derivative aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-pipeline-derivative-aggregation.html) calculates the derivate of the aggregated value.

Basically sub-aggregations are done in the context of an aggregations' bucket, but pipeline aggregations are calculated across buckets (after their values have been computed).